# ember display object value using handlebars markup

Tags: object, ember.js, controller, handlebars.js

I'm new to ember and I would like to know how I can display the values stored in an object controller. I setup a bin and I'm now able to make it work:

http://jsbin.com/xehufetijo/edit?html,js,output

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `model` in from of your attributes. For instance you would write: 
`{{model.first}}` and `{{model.last}}`. If the attributes is attached to a controller, you don't need to specify it explicitly

Comment: + do not forget `data-template-name="index"` http://jsbin.com/gujapiqono/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Great! Thanks much for clarifying. The jsbin i created is actually a very simplified version of my code and i see that if the data-template-name attribute is added, then {{first}} also works.
I actually have separate .hbs templates and js fles under the routes folder. Is there a way to make {{first}} work in my case as well?
Thanks.